# Looping through files and skipping n amount in BASH

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to perform a De Novo assembly in a BASH script using SPAdes. The script works, however the automation is a problem. In this scenario I want to loop through all the files in a specific folder, but for spades you need to add the forward and reverse sequences in one command. The problem is to select the first and second file and then the next loop the third and fourth file. This I can easily do in R, for example, but BASH is not my strong suit.

Here is an example of file names:

```
1_forward.fastq
1_reverse.fastq
2_forward.fastq
2_reverse.fastq
3_forward.fastq
3_reverse.fastq
4_forward.fastq
4_reverse.fastq
```

These are saved under the `${files}` variable.
Here is the spades automated script:

```
 for file in ${files[@]}; do
        spades.py \
            --isolate \
            -1 ${raw_sequences_dir}/${file} \
            -2 ${raw_sequences_dir}/${file} \
            -o ${denovo_output_dir}
    done
```

Again, `-1 1_forward.fastq` and `-2 1_reverse.fastq` has to be run together in the same loop. The next loop should then be `-1 2_forward.fastq` and `-2 2_reverse.fastq` and so on...

Can someone please push me in the correct direction?

Comment: I am unclear on what you are trying to do. You have 1-X _forward/_reverse.fastq files and you say you need 1 & 2 on the 1st iteration, then 4th and 5th .. and then what 7th and 8th, then 10th and 11th?? And what is `X`? how many of the _forward/_reverse pairs of files can be in a directory?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I apologize, I meant in the 1st iteration the 1st and 2nd file and 2nd iteration the 3rd and 4rth file and so on. I will make the edit.

Comment: Oh, you can either keep a counter say `count=1` and use `$count` and `$((count+1))` for `1` and `2` and then `((count+=2))` at the end of the loop. Or, since this is bash, do `for ((count=1; count<X; count+=2)); do` and use the same `$count` and `$((count+1))` to access the wanted indexes/file numbers in each iteration. Would that work? If the `files[]` array has both the _forward and _reverse as separate indexes, then the X (how many indexes) would be `$((${f#iles[@]} / 2))` if that helps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That sounds good, I will give it a... BASH.... hehe

Comment: Good deal. That type of loop in bash is called a "C-style for loop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a `for` loop, incrementing the index by 2 each time through:

```
for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i+=2)); do
    spades.py \
        --isolate \
        -1 "${raw_sequences_dir}/${files[i]}" \
        -2 "${raw_sequences_dir}/${files[i+1]}" \
        -o "${denovo_output_dir}"
 done
```

...but if you're processing all of the files in a particular directory, I'd be tempted to just iterate over the "forward" files, and generate the corresponding "reverse" filenames from them:

```
for fwdfile in "${raw_sequences_dir}"/*forward.fastq; do
    revfile="${fwdfile%forward.fastq}reverse.fastq"
    if [ ! -f "$revfile" ]; then
        echo "missing reverse file $revfile" >&2
        continue
    fi
    spades.py \
        -1 "$fwdfile" \
        -2 "$revfile" \
        -o "${denovo_output_dir}"
 done
```

The trick here is that `${fwdfile%forward.fastq}` gives the forward filename, but with "forward.fastq" removed from the end; so adding "reverse.fastq" gives the corresponding reverse filename.

Comment: It seems when using your first method that the file names are not found by the programs. Any ideas why? It does not seem to recognize the second file name

Comment: If I run the following code to test the loop `for (( i=0; i<${#files[@]}; i+=2 )); do
    echo ${file[$i]}
done` it only produces the last element of the array.

Comment: @roelofco Make sure you use `files` (the array), not `file` (the single-value variable). If that doesn't solve it, put `set -x` before the loop to get an execution trace, and see what the shell thinks is happening. (If there's more to the script, put `set +x` after the loop to turn off tracing.)

Comment: Yes that was the problem it should be `${files}` and not `${file}`. However in the script it is tossing out all the array elements in one line and not individually?

Comment: @roelofco That sounds like the array is malformed. Try `declare -p files` to see what its actual contents are.

Comment: Result: `declare -p files="a_S51_L001_R1_001.fastq
a_S51_L001_R2_001.fastq
b_S48_L001_R1_001.fastq
b_S48_L001_R2_001.fastq
c_S52_L001_R1_001.fastq
c_S52_L001_R2_001.fastq
d_S53_L001_R1_001.fastq
d_S53_L001_R2_001.fastq
e_S49_L001_R1_001.fastq
e_S49_L001_R2_001.fastq"
` Array created like this: `files=$(ls *.fastq)`

Comment: @roelofco That's not an array at all, it's a plain string with spaces between filenames. Try setting it with `files=(*.fastq)` instead.